# Efficiency of engine with two isotherms one isochor and one isobar

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, efficient-energy-use

I was creating a hypothetical engine for fun and trying to calculate the thermal efficiency. The engine which I was trying to calculate consisted of: Isothermal compression, Isobaric expansion, Isothermal compression and Isochoric compression, in that order.
This turns out to be incredibly messy when doing the math.
I used the equation:
$E = W/Qin$
Where $E$ is efficiency, $W$ is the work output and $Qin$ is the heat added to the engine from the hot reservoir.
Obviously my way might not be the best way to solve it for efficiency as I think it may be impossible to simplify with my method, does anyone have a better strategy or an answer(perhaps you tried this for some unknown reason)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Isothermal compression, Isobaric expansion, Isothermal compression and
>   Isochoric compression, in that order.

If the working fluid is a gas, the last process is technically  not a "compression" process. Volume is constant and pressure drops. It is an isochoric heat rejection.

> This turns out to be incredibly messy when doing the math. I used the
>   equation: $E = W/Qin$ Where $E$ is efficiency, $W$ is the work output
>   and $Qin$ is the heat added to the engine from the hot reservoir.

There's nothing particularly messy about it. But you have to keep in mind that $Q_{in}$ for the cycle occurs in two parts of the cycle. First there is heat addition at constant temperature during the isothermal expansion. Second there is heat added during the isobaric expansion. This, however, occurs over a range of temperatures and not just a single temperature. But it is a constant pressure heat addition. Both contributions you should be able to easily calculate with enough information on the equilibrium states 1, 2, 3, and/or 4. Similarly the net work done should be easy to calculate.

Since this borders on a homework and exercise type question, I can not and will not solve it for you. But the above should be enable you to do so. So simplify matters assume it's an ideal gas. Then the ideal gas equation coupled with the first law for a closed system, sufficient equilibrium state data, and the equations for the different processes is all you need.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to even come close to matching your result for the efficiency.  In my judgment, the approach should be to express the efficiency in terms of as few process parameters as possible.  Using the approach I have outlined below, it can be done using only two process parameters, $P_2/P_1$ and $T_H/T_C$.

In terms of $V_1$, the volumes at points 2 and 3, based on the ideal gas law, are:
$$V_2=V_1\frac{P_1}{P_2}$$
$$V_3=V_2\frac{T_H}{T_C}=V_1\frac{P_1}{P_2}\frac{T_H}{T_C}$$

Based on these results, the four heat flows are:
$$Q_{12}=nRT_C\ln{(V_2/V_1)}=-nRT_C\ln{(P_2/P_1)}$$
$$Q_{23}=nC_P(T_H-T_C)$$
$$Q_{34}=nRT_H\ln{(V_1/V_3)}=nRT_H[\ln{(P_2/P_1)}+\ln{(T_C/T_H)}]$$
$$Q_{41}=-nC_v(T_H-T_C)$$
The rest is straightforward.